# Mail takes a long time to send

Tags: email, powershell, outlook, powershell-ise, outlook-redemption

I'm writing a script that can send mails to a certain e-mail address but I'm having some trouble with the sending itself.

The problem is that when I send a mail with the script it takes approximately 1min to send. I can see this because I can see it in my outbox.
But when I create this exact same mail manually in outlook it only takes a matter of seconds to process and send the mail.

#### My code for creating and sending the mail:

(I use Redemption)

```
    $mItem = $ol.CreateItem(0)
    $mail = $routlook.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject($mItem)

    $mail.To = "<Recipient's Address>"
    $mail.Subject = "Some Subject"
    $mail.Body = "Some Body"
    $mail.Attachments.Add("<Path to Attachment>")
    $mail.DeleteAfterSubmit = $True

    $mail.Send()
```

I don't know what the problem is. Could this be due to my code? or perhaps the exchange-server or the Outlook client?

How can I make the mails from the script send faster?

Please help,

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean it takes 1 minute to run the script above? Or it takes 1 minute after the script runs until the message is actually sent? In the later case, please see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#1.

Comment: well, the latter. My script runs timely, mail is sent timely. But it's stuck in the Outbox for 1+ minute before it's sent out.(instead of drafts, mentioned in Link). I tested code provided in your link in powershell (witch correct syntax) but it doesn't help my problem.

Comment: What have you tried? Keep in mind that MAPIUtils.DeliverNow has not worked since Outlook 2002.

Comment: Have tried to create `Redemption.MAPIUtils` object and use `DeliverNow` but it doesn't work. other than that you have not provided any other information.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#1.? You can also use Namespace.SendAndReceive orr SyncObject.Start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [send-mailmessage](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849925.aspx) directly in your code without the long way through COM and Outlook.

Comment: Can't use this method, already tried. Gets denied due to policy reasons.Too unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an Exchange version of at least 2007, you'd be much better off using the EWS Managed API than Outlook/COM.

Comment: yes 2010. But I have No idea what you're referring to

Comment: Here's an example: http://mikepfeiffer.net/2010/04/sending-email-with-powershell-and-the-ews-managed-api/